# Go net/http handle func with dynamic uri segment

Tags: go

How i can use dynamic uri segment in Go net/http ? for example

```
http.HandleFunc("/<user_id>/<file_id>", HelloServer)
```

it is possible to do this with only Go built-in net/http ?

Comment: Well, yes. You can do absolutely any routing you want - `net/http` just passes the request to a handler. The built-in mux doesn't support this kind of routing though, so you'd have to write your own path handling logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Register a handler for "/" and dispatch dynamic paths in that handler:

```
 http.HandleFunc("/", RootServer)
```

Register other handlers with static paths as normal:

```
 http.HandleFunc("/about", AboutServer)
```

The [default server mux](https://godoc.org/net/http#DefaultServeMux) dispatches all requests that don't match some other registered path to the handler registered for "/".  Write code in that handler to dispatch on the request path. Here's an example:

```
func RootServer(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.URL.Path == "/" {
        IndexServer(w, r) // handle root document on site
    } else if uid, fid, ok := matchUserFile(r.URL.Path), ok {
        UserFileServer(w, r, uid, fid)
    } else {
        http.Error(w, "Not Found", http.StatusNotFound)
    }
}
```

The function `matchUserFile` looks something like this:

```
func matchUserFile(path string) (uid string, fid string, ok bool) {
    // if path matches the /<user_id>/<file_id> pattern then 
    //    return user id, file id, true
    // else
    //    return "", "", false
}
```

There are many ways to write `matchUserFile` function. [Regular expressions](https://godoc.org/regexp) may be helpful in the implementation.

Comment: Note that there's no point in doing `http.HandleFunc("/", HelloServer)`, it just adds a mux that doesn't do anything. Just use `http.ListenAndServe(":80", HelloServer)`.

Comment: this is so confusing for novice like me,

Comment: @LoboNokeweNgewe Is there something more specific about what you find confusing?

Comment: @LoboNokeweNgewe If this is confusing, then consider using an HTTP router that supports this natively. [chi](https://github.com/go-chi/chi) is my favorite. [gorilla/mux](https://github.com/gorilla/mux) is another popular choice. There are dozens others which you can find on Google.